# How to add additional if statement to an existing javascript function for screen width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I have a Javascript code where I would like to add an additional rule for the if statement- if the screen width is below 767px, then keep the CSS class attribute 'av_header_transparency' Below is the code in question:

```js
if (transparent) {
    if (st > 50) {
    //header.removeClass('av_header_transparency');
        av_change_class(header, 'remove', 'av_header_transparency');
    } else {
        //header.addClass('av_header_transparency');
        av_change_class(header, 'add', 'av_header_transparency');
    }
}
```

Currently this code is removing a CSS class 'av_header_transparency' if scrolling down for 50px, but I would like to keep this on mobile screen. Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: Maybe use CSS media queries to have that class behave differently on mobile

Comment: Thanks, but st > 50  is telling how much you need to scroll down for the CSS removal rule to apply. I need to keep the class if the screen width is below 768px, like on CSS we do it with @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) I just don`t know anything about JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure its explained properly, but you could check screen width before removing it, so something like

```
if(transparent)
{   
    if(st > 50 && window.innerWidth >767)
    {   
                //header.removeClass('av_header_transparency');
        av_change_class(header, 'remove', 'av_header_transparency');
    }
    else
    {
        //header.addClass('av_header_transparency');
        av_change_class(header, 'add', 'av_header_transparency');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just put 767px into your code. And you should compare it to a string.

Comment: Thanks Simon this worked like a charm! Awesome community!

Answer (score 1):

CSS Media Queries are perfect for this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {

  header.someClass {
    /* styles for screeens up to 767px */
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {

  header.someClass {
    /* styles for screeens larger than 768px */
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I really needed to do this inside the JS code.